# MVC 4 + Entity Framework 5 + Stored Procedures

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

> I'm just now teaching myself MVC4 (did webform for years), and I'm
>   frustrated - but not about MVC which is pretty good.  Entity Framework
>   is...well

I'm using VS2010.

The problem

We have a real database, you know normalized with like foreign keys and stuff.  But every example I find for Entity Framework is direct to the table, but we rarely have a straight table pull - out side of populating dropdowns and such.  All of our frontend calls hit a Stored Proc (how old school! *expletive deleted*)

I love the Model architecture of MVC where you define the attributes of the data coming from the data source - Display Name, Ranges, DataType. etc.  So I definitely want to keep this.

Entity Framework and MVC do not want to play well in this senario.  I created my edmx file (with SPs only), did my function import for a SP, everything is good....'til now.

Can't Create a Controller from the edmx/designer - Enter Controller Name, pick MVC controller with read using EF, pick the model class that is the FuntionName_Result, and for context pick the ...Entities name.  FAIL Unable to retrieve metadata

OK, so now I try EF 5.x DbContext Generator, update the file name and boom I have a model and context - awesome now I can do the cool MVC stuff, lets rebuild the site....oh the horror - everything has been previously defined.

I tried generating the edmx in a different folder and/or deleting it after the DBContext generator, still can't create Controller.

```
'blah' is not part of the specified 'Context' class, and the 'Context' class could not be modifed to add a 'DbSet' property to it. (For example, the 'Context' class might be in a compiled assembly.)
```

IF I manually add the DBSet, I'm back to unable to retreive metadata - I am assuming this is happening because it can't connect to the DB.  I don't know where to tell it to use the connection string in web.config. - if this is the problem

Here lies dead my MVC hopes of a brighter future.

What am I missing?

I am not married to EF, so if there is a better way to access databases (without writing all the code from scratch) I'm here to listen.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Entity framework relies heavily on conventions.  It takes a little bit to get used to.  For example for connection strings...  If entity framework doesn't find a connection string with the same name as your DBcontext class it just makes one (i think it defaults to using the project name as the database name).  If this database doesn't exist it will create it locally as a sql express DB.  This leads to the kinds of errors like the ones you are reporting.

If you want to define the connection string for entity framework all you need to do is provide a connection string in the web.config.  Again conventions.... the connection string should be named the same as your DBContext class and entity framework will just find it.

```
<connectionStrings>
      <add name="MyDbContextClassName" connectionString="..." />
</connectionStrings>
```

On an architecture note,  IMHO ORM's are defiantly the way to go for new application development.  It makes getting data into and out of your database soo much easier.  That said it is a **Big** paradigm shift if you are used to accessing everything via sprocs and direct queries to the DB.  Don't give up on it.  It will frustrate you at first just like picking up any new tech, but it's well worth it in the end.

I have used entity framework and nHibernate for ORM in the past.  The thing that I like about entity framework is that if you use code first migration most of the really annoying, tedious, and error prone column mappings are auto generated for you (again using conventions).  You sometimes still end up having to do a little mapping but those cases are pretty rare.  Maybe a little less rare if you already have a database since your column names will probably not always match entity frameworks conventions.  Anyway... This is a big plus in my book and why I would defiantly favor EF over nHibernate.

Comment: Not to mention that EF 6 is going to support Stored Procs. Yet another good reason to make the push.

Comment: Thanks Ben. At this point I have been able to bring data up from the DB using the code generated by EF.  However, I am now looking at other ORMs - specifically PetaPOCO.

Comment: So did this answer your question or no?  If no, please clarify and I'll see if I can provide more help.

Comment: @Ben.  Since I let the process create its own connection string, I don't think it was a connection issue, for the initial problem.  I'm sure it was when I started manipulating EF (like deleting the edmx).  I find the "Big paradigm shift" going backwards in time, this industry tends to forget its past sins and then repeat them.

Comment: @IronMan84 Thanks for the heads up, I guess I'll be waiting for EF6.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a database, with stored procedures you do not need the EF 5.X DbContext Generator. Create either a folder in your project or a new project in your solution for your data access. In that folder/project add a edmx file and configure it to an existing database using the wizard. At this stage you can pull in your stored procedures.

If you open the edmx file, you can go to the model explorer tab and manage the imported functions (stored procs) and their return types.

Once you have that, In your controller, rather than using an instance of DbContext you can just use an instance of your EF Entities. So if you called your edmx 'MyDbAccess' you should be able to use MyDbAccessEntities which will then allow you to access the stored procedures.

Answer (score 0):

I in your App.config file check your

```
<connectionStrings>
```

After check if your stored procedures are added in the model context file

```
YouDBModel.Context.tt
   > YourBDModel.Context.cs
```